# Laravel - I am successfully pass start and end price range with ajax get request but can not return in right way

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

[Array Result after click price range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AHPO.png)Here I am trying to fetch products by passing price range inputs to controller function:

```
<script>
function send(){

 var start = $('#amount_start').val();

 var end = $('#amount_end').val();

 //var dataString = "start" + start;
    $.ajax({  
        type: 'get',  
        url: 'shop', 
        data: "start=" + start + "&end=" + end,

        success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        }

    });
 }
```

**Controller:**

```
if ($request->ajax()) { 
        $start = $request->start;
        $end = $request->end;
        $Products = DB::table('products')->get();

        return view('front.test')->with('Products', $Products);
    } else {
        $Products = DB::table('products')->paginate(6); 
        return view('front.shop', compact('Products'));
    }
```

**View File:**

```
<label for="amount">Price range:</label>

<input type="text" id="amount_start" name="start_price" value="70" />

<input type="text" id="amount_end"  name="end_price" value="150" />

<div id="slider-range"></div>

<button onclick="send()">Click me</button>
```

can you please help me around for some solution?

Comment: what do you mean by "can not return in right way"?

Comment: try with `url: '/shop',` ?

Comment: my else part is working always

i mean to say products not changing according to my price rang,
i able see right products in console.log but not in my view

Comment: @hardeepcoder you mean when you go to "/shop", it show you it doesn't show right product but when you do with ajax part it show correct data ?

Comment: @SupunFictionPraneeth its howing right products in array but in products listing(html) showing from else part (default products).

how can i update my Divs according to arrays ?

Array result in view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AHPO.png

Answer (score 1):

Ad the following to your ajax success to append the view to the page:

```
 success: function(response) {
      $('body').append(response);//change the selector if you want to be more precise with your appended data
    }
```

Note: make sure that the view you return is not a whole page but only the necessary data

Also note that you can't use laravel paginate with ajax

Answer (score 0):

Change your return statement for ajax calls

```
if ($request->ajax()) { 
    ...
    return response()->json($Products); //return to ajax
} else {
    ...
    return view('front.shop', compact('Products')); //return a view to page
}
```

Comment: so then how i will return data for my view
like  return view('front.shop', compact('Products'));

and from input i able for fetch only two prices range 
i want to display products according to that price range

Comment: The else part will take part of that.

Comment: @EddyTheDove still brother only else part is running i think.
i can see right result in console but my products not changing in view.

Comment: Ok. This solved your first probleme. Getting the result through Ajax. That's why you see them in the console now. Now, please ask another question (Search first) how to update your html with ajax result.

Comment: @madalinivascu he also wants his list of products to change in the view. But without reloading the page.

Comment: @EddyTheDove yes, i want products list according to price rang witch we are passing from input.
but currently its showing according to my else part code.

Comment: My answer just solved the first part of your question. How to return properly an ajax request. For the second part, which is updating your current view with ajax results, please, see @madalinivascu answer or google how to do that.